# Intercambio filas por columnas - PAscal

Tags: array, pascal

Os pido ayuda de nuevo con un ejercicio: se trata de intercambiar filas por columnas en un array.
Es un array de 7 filas y 3 columnas con letras aleatorias de la "A" a la "U". Sale en un primer lugar, y cuando imprima todo el array necesito que lo haga por filas en lugar de imprimir las columnas de arriba a abajo.
Os pongo un ejemplo mas visual y adjunto el código fuente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
for it1:= 1 to MAX_TARJETAS_GRUPO{7} do begin
     for it2:=1 to MAX_GRUPOS{3} do begin
       if it2=1 then begin
            write(grupo2[it1],' ');
            end else if it2=2 then begin
            write(grupo1[it1],' ');
       end else begin
         write(grupo3[it1]);
       end;
     end;
     writeln;
   end;
```

Comment: Leí tu pregunta dos veces y no comprendo lo que quieres lograr o cuál es el problema con tu código. Quizás se dificulta porque el código no coincide con lo que afirmas, por ejemplo tienes tres arrays (en realidad tres vectores) y no uno. Y en la imagen pones un texto "selecciona primera columna" que no se ve dónde se imprime, por lo que queda claro que no produces esa salida con ese código.